# Read/write bytes from/to kernel network driver to test a custom TCP/IP stack

Tags: linux, tcp, linux-kernel, network-programming, ip

I am writing my own TCP/IP stack.

I would like to test it still using my NIC's kernel driver and hijacking packets after the network driver. However, I need to prevent the kernel doing further processing, otherwise we could both transmit TCP ACKs etc.

I will parse the packets and transmit any responses.

What is the best way to achieve this?

I thought I could use a raw socket, but I believe that will just send me a copy and the kernel will continue processing.

I found the Linux kernel module Netfilter, which looks good for receiving but I'm not sure how I would do the transmit?

It would be useful if Wireshark could see the packets received/transmitted. However, I understand this may conflict with my requirement for the kernel to not do much processing.

I just want to read/write raw bytes from/to my network card kernel driver.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/56092/64699

Comment: A full network stack includes the network interface driver. Having your own driver gives you direct layer-2 frames (you need that to do ARP) and lets you connect it directly to your layer-3 interface to send the packets that are the payload of the frames that you connect directly to your layer-4 interface to give it the datagrams or segments that are the payload of the packets, and there you have your own network stack.

Comment: @RonMaupin I'm writing this to use with DPDK, so I will use their driver. However, I wanted to test my partial-stack before using DPDK and was wondering if there is a way.